# Unable to access json data in function

Tags: jquery, json, dropzone.js

I am getting this data from server as JSON response:

```
{
    "success": true,
    "status": "success",
    "path": "http:\/\/www.images.site.com\/profile\/large\/",
    "smallpath": "http:\/\/www.images.site.com\/profile\/small\/",
    "smpath": "http:\/\/www.images.site.com\/profile\/sm\/"
}
```

How can I access it on jQuery success? I tried this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#img").dropzone({
        paramName: "file",
        maxFiles: 1,
        url: 'http://images.site.com/aac.php',
        init: function () {
            this.on("success", function (file, dd) {
                console.log("log " + dd.length);
                console.log("log " + dd.success);
                console.log("sd" + dd.path);
            }).fail(function () {
                alert("error");
            });
         }
        });
```

I get an error:

> log Invalid JSON response from server

I'm using dropzone.js for file uploading

Comment: Can you add the code that you are using to fetch the data from the server? Primarily what `this` is referencing

Comment: please see question again. bracket may mishmetch here it is correctly closed

Answer (score 0):

Try change

`dd.length`

to this

`Object.keys(dd).length`

I tried to `console.log(dd.length)` and it shows `undefined` and `Object.keys(dd).length` works well.

Comment: but as I know to access success fron json response I have to do dd.success it is show value of success what may be the problem

Comment: You got error: `log Invalid JSON response from server` and you call first this line `console.log("log " + dd.length);`. So `Invalid JSON response from server` is `dd.length`.  I think it gets error and stops here. Try to change to `console.log("log1 " + dd.length);` and you will see were script stops. For me `dd.success` works well and `dd.length` shows `undefined`

Comment: In script you don't use `dataType` argument.  Try to add `dataType: "json"`. Sometimes it helps.

Comment: You can check  headers that comes in response from server it should be `application/json`  `$headers =  getallheaders();`